# Hive server 2 not starting

Tags: hive, cloudera

I have Hadoop 2.8.0 and I have installed Hive 2.1.0 on a single node, but Hive server is not starting.

[image: hive error screenshot]

Comment: anyone, please help me out from this. I have uploaded my error screenshot also

Answer (score 3):

it seems like your problem is with your hive metastore I suggest you to  restart thrift server from same directory from where you create the metastore